# React Native Communication between devices using Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are building a mobile application for Covid-19 tracking. We wanted to use Bluetooth LE to communicate between devices and we are writing our app with React Native. Currently, we are using `react-native-peripheral` for advertising data and `react-native-ble-plx` for receiving data. We want to be able to send two different types of data separately from the same device, with a delay of `n` seconds. Our intended workflow for the advertising device is as follows:

- Create a characteristic and a service
- Start advertising
- Stop advertising after 10 seconds
- Remove previously added service
- Wait `n` seconds
- Create another characteristic and service
- Start advertising again but with different name
- Stop after 10 seconds again

Our code for advertising is as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Peripheral.onStateChanged((state) => {
      // wait until Bluetooth is ready
      if (state === "poweredOn") {
        // first, define a characteristic with a value
        const ch1 = new Characteristic({
          uuid: "",
          value: "", 
          properties: ["read", "write"],
          permissions: ["readable", "writeable"],
        });
        const ch2 = new Characteristic({
          uuid: "",
          value: "", 
          properties: ["read", "write"],
          permissions: ["readable", "writeable"],
        });

        const serviceUuid1 = "";
        const serviceUuid2 = "";

        const service1 = new Service({
          uuid: serviceUuid1,
          characteristics: [ch1],
        });
        const service2 = new Service({
          uuid: serviceUuid2,
          characteristics: [ch2],
        });

        // register GATT services that your device provides
        Peripheral.addService(service1)
          .then(() => {
            // start advertising to make your device discoverable
            console.log("starting advertising...");
            setMessage("starting advertising...");
            Peripheral.startAdvertising({
              name: "foo",
              serviceUuids: [serviceUuid1],
            });
          })
          .then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              Peripheral.stopAdvertising();
              console.log("stopping advertising...");
              setMessage("stopping advertising...");
            }, 10000);
          });

        setTimeout(() => {
          Peripheral.addService(service2)
            .then(() => {
              // start advertising to make your device discoverable
              console.log("starting advertising second time...");
              setMessage("starting advertising second time...");
              Peripheral.startAdvertising({
                name: "bar",
                serviceUuids: [serviceUuid2],
              });
            })
            .then(() => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                Peripheral.stopAdvertising();
                console.log("stopping advertising second time...");
                setMessage("stopping advertising second time...");
              }, 22000);
            });
        }, 12000);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

(UUID values are randomly generated and assigned to service and characteristic UUID variables).

Our current problem is that we cannot advertise two types of data sequentially with different device names, services and characteristics. I wanted to ask if that is even possible to perform this function in React Native.

After a few failed attempts, we wanted to send two different services simultaneously with the same name, but we think it does not work either. We observed that the advertising device is sending data when its Bluetooth is enabled, even though the app is closed. Can it be a problem caused by the bluetooth cache of one of the devices? If so, does React Native support a package which is able to clear the devices' Bluetooth cache?

I know I asked a lot of questions but we are very confused as a team right now, as we are not very familar with BLE and React Native. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Comment: First, what you are trying to do is hard. Second I doubt you will be able to do it successfully in a cross platform app. You will probably need to write two native apps that use equivalent code in order to work closely enough with the operating system. There are government solutions that have been open sourced including solutions from the Singapore Govt and the Australian Govt. Third Apple, in particular, has restrictions so that only government and recognised health bodies can publish Covid tracing apps in the App Store.

Comment: I'll admit that React Native was not the optimal choice for our design but we are too invested now to make a fundamental change such as switching to native apps. Moreover, we have a time limitation. We will present our application as a proof of concept for an attendance application which also has privacy-preserving Covid-19 tracking feature, so it will not necessarily be published.

Comment: Randomising the service will cause problems since other devices won't know what service they are looking for. When an iOS app is in the background it cannot discover "all services" it has to look for a specific service uuid. You could randomise the value of a characteristic on the service while keeping the service and characteristic identifiers consistent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid response. We thought of using randomized service and char uuids so that the advertising device could not be traced and user privacy could be preserved. Would it still be a problem if we only need the scan&discovery function when the app is working in foreground?

Comment: In the foreground you can scan for all services and then you will need to connect and read the characteristics and data to see if it is a service you are interested in but you will probably find that unpublished services kind of hang around.  Service names are typically not discoverable by other devices either.

Comment: Do these unpublished services have something to do with advertising device's bluetooth cache? When we connect to an advertising device to which we added 2 services before executing the startAdvertising() command, it shows 9 to 11 services. Could those be some unpublished services that you mentioned?